# Xamarin.ios UI freezing

Tags: c#, xcode, multithreading, user-interface, xamarin.ios

I have a Xamarin.ios application which uses MySql. I want to show a IUActivityIndicatorView while program is trying to get data from MySql database.

I tried the code below and the activity indicator appeared after data load which means the UI is freezing. I searched about background workers in Xamarin.ios but I enden up with nothing.

The code that I have tried:

```
Task.Run(indicator.StartAnimating);
```

I tried it without Task.Run as well but the result is the same.

Comment: you need to provide more than a single line of code to illustrate what you are doing

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making the indicator.StartAnimating code line work on another thread, I changed the MySql method's thread by the following code:

```
new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(() => {
    InvokeOnMainThread(() => {
      MySqlMethod();
    });
})).Start();
```

Comment: I want to give an extra information to people who has same problem, `InvokeOnMainThread` is essential, otherwise the program will crash.